# SharePoint creating web application on APP instead of WFE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, central-administration, web-application

I have one APP and one WFE server.

**Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application** service is stopped on APP but is running on WFE.

When I go to CA to create a new Web Application, in the URL field it is showing me `http://APP`.
How do I create web application on WFE? If I simply change it to `http://WFE` will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your APP and WFE server are all part of the same farm.

That Web Application service is running on WFE only is because WFE is ment to serve web requests from IIS and APP server (usually) are ment to run service applications.

The reason that your URL field shows up as `http://APP` is probably because you haven't specified a hostname in your web application so it defaults to server name. If you want another URL on your web application you can simply create an Alternate Access Mapping (AAM) on your web application called `http://contoso.com` or what ever you want.

More info on AAM

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx

Comment: So basically this is normal and if I create this web application, it will actually create it on my WFE and not APP even though the URL says APP, right?

Comment: Ok I changed the URL to WFE while creating web application and it is working fine. Since this is just development farm so I am not going with that other option of creating host header and AAM.